# Is it possible to evaluate $n!$ in $O(1)$?

Tags: time-complexity, mathematical-programming

I'm working on a formula that'll evaluate the partial sum of the harmonic series from $t_1$ to $t_n$. The problem is that I'm almost certain the final formula will include factorials. But if the formula has a factorial, then it's runtime complexity would be at least $O(n)$. And this would defeat the entire point of having a general formula, because I can just iterate over the first $n$ terms and add those in $O(n)$. Utilizing the gamma function wouldn't help either since it'll require $n$ "integration by parts" steps. So is there any way to evaluate factorials faster than $O(n)$?

Comment: might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2327301/3768871

Comment: @OmG Thanks, but I've already viewed that page. My question is that can there exist a faster algorithm?

Comment: He answered "no"!

Comment: What is $n$? The number whose factorial you're trying to compute, or its length in bits? What model of computation are you using?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes, the number I'm trying to compute the factorial of.

Comment: @OmG From what I could see, the majority of the page just consisted of worrying about multiplication of non-fixed integer sizes and the runtime of that.

Comment: O(1) *in what*? What is the machine model? Generally speaking, the result has n log n bits, so arguably it can't even be written in constant (or linear) time.

Comment: @Raphael The size of the number will be fixed with an upper bound and everything.

Answer (score 1):

There are two scenarios:

1. Your integers are of fixed size. Then, you absolutely can compute $n!$ in $O(1)$. In fact, every algorithm that computes $n!$ satisfies this. Why? There are finitely many inputs to your algorithm. If it takes $f(n)$ steps to compute $n!$, and there are finitely many $n$ values, then there must be some maximum for $f$. That's the upper bound on your runtime.

   Is this answer useful? No, since it doesn't give you any hints as for how to speed up an algorithm. But, it hints that maybe Big-O notation isn't an accurate measure of time for your particular application.
2. Your integers are of unbounded. Then there can't be an $O(1)$ way to compute it.

   How do we know? Well, suppose you have an algorithm that takes at most $k$ steps for any input. Give it an input with $k+1$ bits. It can't possibly examine each bit, since looking up a bit requires a step. So your algorithm only looks at $k$ bits of the $k+1$-length function. But then, if you give the same input with the ignored bit flipped, it will give the same answer! This is impossible, since factorial is an injective function. Flipping a bit should always give us a different answer, so we must examine each bit, so we can't compute it in $O(n)$.

Comment: Sorry, didn't think of that haha. But what I mean is an algorithm that takes the least amount of steps possible. I've managed to come up with an algorithm that takes out the even numbers and only multiplies the odds, then uses the sum formula to calculate the value of $k$ for $2^k$ (the value that'll be multiplied at the end, because we took out every multiple of 2). So even though this algorithm is twice as fast, it's still linear. But it at least gives me hope that faster algorithms do exist.

Comment: Usually reading time is ignored so, for example, there is a way to compute $2^N$ in $O(\log N)$ time.

Comment: @rus9384 How you write the N-bit result in that time?

Comment: @Raphael do operations on output tape count? Then trivially calculating $f(x_0)$ in some point $x_0$ requires $\log f(x_0)$ time.

Comment: @rus9384 Depends on the model you assume. I assumed you were in jmite's case 2, in which you'd need to write N/k numbers. That's similar to counting tape symbols, scaled by a factor of 1/k.